# custom tabbar in uiviewcontroller only on few scene

Tags: uitabbar, navigationbar

i have `NavigationController` base application but i need `TabBar` in the bottom only on the Two Scene not for the whole app. Anyone have any idea about it.
Waiting your kind response.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution By creating a very simple thing as making a `UIView` using storyboard and add Button of custom type and then push and pop ViewControllers by using Following button actions

```
- (IBAction)pushToSecondVC:(id)sender {

UIViewController *tab2vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tab2vc animated:NO];
```

}

and for the back button in the second `ViewController`

```
-(IBAction)goBackToPreviousController:(id)sender{

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

}